# How can I implement a case class with several separate public interfaces?

Tags: scala, immutability

What I tried:

```
object LolTest {
    trait Foo {
        def foo: Int // getter
        def foo(i: Int): Foo // setter
    }

    trait Bar {
        def bar: String // getter
        def bar(s: String): Bar // setter
    }

    case class Buzz(foo: Int, bar: String) extends Foo with Bar {
        override def foo(i: Int): Buzz = copy(foo = i)
        override def bar(s: String): Buzz = copy(bar = s)
    }
}
```

But my real class should have many fields (around 10). And having to implement the setters (updaters, transformers?) in the concrete class instead of traits looks ... wrong. And I'm having more and more problems trying to add different setters for the class.

I'd appreciate an advice on this problem.

Comment: Why not simply use a case class with that ten fields? https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/2-language-rules.md#24-should-not-define-useless-traits

Comment: @leshkin: to encapsulate different "views" of the class by different users. "Program to interface" and all that.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to implement "setters" for your case classes. I would do it like this:

```
scala> case class A(a: Int, b: String = "hi", c: Boolean = false)
defined class A

scala> A(1)
res0: A = A(1,hi,false)

scala> A(1, "bye")
res1: A = A(1,bye,false)

scala> A(1, "bye", true)
res2: A = A(1,bye,true)

scala> res2.copy(b = "actually hi")
res3: A = A(1,actually hi,true)
```

In this example `a` is required. If you want an example where you can construct an `A` only specifying `b`, give a default value for `a` in your case class definition:

```
scala> case class A(a: Int = 1, b: String = "hi", c: Boolean = false)
defined class A

scala> A(b = "only change the middle")
res9: A = A(1,only change the middle,false)
```